# obfs4 bridge every 10-20 seconds send and receive some data on static or default browser pages

Tags: onion-routing, obfs4

Is it kind of normal experience?
When I'm just on static, already downloaded page or default Tor browser page, in network statistics on PC every ~5-10-20 sec small unidentified packets send or receive some unclear data.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that could affect traffic timing:

1. Javascript, especially for advertisements, could be periodically uploading/downloading data (for example reporting back to the ad service or downloading new images).
2. Tor itself sends padding cells randomly following the [padding spec](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/padding-spec.txt).
3. Obfs4 can delay traffic, but I don't believe it sends its own periodic cover traffic.

So my guess is that you're seeing Tor's padding traffic. If you disable Obfs4, you should still see this traffic.